# How to fix my rendered content when pasting my website link into address bar or clicking on a hyperlink going to my website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on My portfolio React site and it is stored in my GitHub repository, whenever I cut and paste the link into an address bar or click on a hyperlink going to my portfolio page the only thing that shows is the header and the footer with blank white space in-between. The only way I can get the site to show the site is that I have to click on other links on the site first so my homepage can render. Then all is well everything renders properly.

I have deleted the repository and reinstalled React web site again, then I checked my Router imports

This is how I have my apps component setup

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import {
  Layout,
  Header,
  Navigation,
  Drawer,
  Content,
  Footer,
  FooterLinkList,
  FooterSection
} from "react-mdl";
import Main from "./components/main";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-big-content">
        <Layout>
          <Header
            className="header-color"
            title={
              <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "white" }} to="/">
                David Piper
              </Link>
            }
            scroll
          >
            <Navigation>
              <Link to="/resume">Resume</Link>
              <Link to="/aboutme">About Me</Link>
              <Link to="/projects">Projects</Link>
              <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
            </Navigation>
          </Header>
          <Drawer
            title={
              <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }} to="/">
                David Piper
              </Link>
            }
          >
            <Navigation>
              <Link to="/resume">Resume</Link>
              <Link to="/aboutme">About Me</Link>
              <Link to="/projects">Projects</Link>
              <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
            </Navigation>
          </Drawer>

          <Content>
            <div className="page-content" />
            <Main />
          </Content>

          <Footer className="header-color" size="mini">
            <FooterSection type="left" logo="Title">
              <FooterLinkList>
                <Link to="/">Help</Link>
                <Link to="/">Privacy & Terms</Link>
              </FooterLinkList>
            </FooterSection>
          </Footer>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my portfolio page link
https://dvd2x.github.io/dpiper-portfolio/

I expect that whenever I cut and paste the link into the address bar or hyperlink to the site that all content renders like normal

Comment: I'm guessing you're using react-router, where's your router code? You probably just need to specify a component for the `/` path, but there's not enough to go on here.

Comment: This is the rest of the App component:                                                                                 import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout>
          <Header />
            <Navigation />
          <Drawer />
            <Navigation />
          <Content>
            <div className="page-content" />
            <Main />
          </Content>
          <Footer className="header-color" size="mini"/>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

Comment: @DavidBey, Please edit the question to add relevant code than commenting on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying single page applications to Github pages can be tricky. The reason is that Github is not serving your page from the root url `/`, but is instead serving your page from `/dpiper-portfolio`. So, react router attempts to match `/dpiper-portfolio`, but finds nothing, so it serves no route.

Try setting a [basename in react router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) like this. You'll need to use react router v4 or later.

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/dpiper-portfolio">...</BrowserRouter>
```

You might also want to set the basename conditionally depending on whether you are in development or production. Otherwise, you will have to develope at `localhost:3000/dpiper-portfolio` as opposed to just `localhost:3000`

**Another option** is to use a Github [user page](https://help.github.com/en/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#user-and-organization-pages-sites) instead of a project page. Unlike project pages which are not served from the root but instead `username.github.io/projectname`, user pages are served from the root url `<username>.github.io` which would eliminate this issue.

Comment: Thank you this was the fix that I needed after adding basename everything renders perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your react router setting. If you are using resume component as your homepage you need to set your route like this

```
import Resume from './componentdirectory/resume'
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';


<BrowserRouter>
         <Header></Header> 
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Resume} exact/>
                </Switch>
         <Footer></Footer>
</BrowserRouter>
```